# Conflict between aws-s3 gem and aws-sdk gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I am using rails 3.2.1 and ruby 1.9.2. I need to use both `aws-sdk` gem and `aws-s3` gem simultaneously. When I add `aws-sdk` gem, `AWS::S3::Base` becomes uninitialized. I found some solutions which suggests to use `new()` instead of `establish_connection`. But I have to use `establish_connection()` due to some other reasons. Is it possible to call `AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection()`  even when `aws-sdk` gem is installed?

Comment: Seems like both gems use same namespace so I don't think it will be possible to use them both. Are you sure none of them provides all required functionality?

Comment: When I add aws-sdk, some of the used features of aws-s3 got depricated.

Comment: My project is too big. It will be a trouble for me if it requires to upgrade my previous code.

Comment: you can use ruby fog http://fog.io/